# copy wordpress site to localhost

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, ftp

I've got xampp up and running, copied the files of sikkesautomobielen.nl via FTP to my htdocs, connected my php database and have got my duplicate site working (localhost). When I click on one of the links on the site I still end up on sikkesautomobielen.nl instead of my localhost. I guess it's a database issue. Is there an easy way for me to make the URLs reference to localhost instead of sikkesautomobielen? I'm trying to develop a Wordpress site and when I'm done, I would like to upload it to the server. This way the site has a minimal down time and I can afford myself some mistakes without the "official" site crashing.

Comment: Follow the second part of the answer I gave some time ago. http://stackoverflow.com/a/31579401/629127. The easiest way is to copy everything, copy the base on your localhost and then preform search-replace to replace old with the new links...

Answer (score 1):

It's a database issue. Go to your database( PHPMyAdmin) and under *_options you will find 2 base urls, change them to your localhost url and the site will work.

Change the 'option_value' of both 'home' & 'siteurl'

'*' refers to your selected prefix

Comment: Never do a search and replace in your WordPress database for URLs you will break things. Just stick to the _options table and change the values for "siteurl" and "home" - if you still find you have issues with links take a look at https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/ which is a nice plugin that correctly replaces urls for you without breaking the db

Comment: i never had a situation where it didn't work after the options table, so i didn't know that , ty

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm pretty new at this. Should I open a .php file or can I find *_options via localhost/phpmyadmiin?

Comment: @asgeira , go to your phpmyadmin. the * is to say that it will be called whatever your database prefix is , if it's standard(which is bad for security) it will be called wp_options etc,..

Comment: Okay, I tried that but I broke the site. The theme doesn't work and when I click an item in the menu i still end up at sikkesautomobielen.nl instead of localhost. I edited the "option value" at table "wp_options" and entered Localhost. That's not that difficult. By the way, if I change it back I also get "page not found". Also wp-admin doesn't exist, so I guess there's really something wrong here.

Comment: Did you exported your database correctly? And is your wordpress config referring to that new database adress? You have to change both the 'siteurl' and 'home' option_value. Also change it to http://localhost  . And is your localhost actually called localhost or do you have a custom url setup like dev.local/ or something?

Comment: In your options table in PHPMyAdmin you change these two fields  "siteurl" and "home" which should be referring to the live site - change the url to match your local site url.

Comment: @Christophvh some of the data in the db is saved as serialized arrays (plain text versions of arrays - which have character counts etc... so if you change a url that changes the text and the count no longer matches up and things break) all good fun :)